# discord.jsで返信の際に言及しないようにしたい

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

下記のコードを実行したらメッセージは返信されましたが言及されてしまいました。
どなたか言及されない方法を教えてください。
v13です。

```
message.reply({
  content: "hoge"
  allowedMentions: {
    parse: []
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

コードの形がv12なのと、`[ ]` があるのでTypeScriptでは？
確認した方がいいと思います。

以下はv13のコードです！頑張ってください！

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.includes('<反応するワード>')) {
        message.channel.send('<Botが返す文章>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

他の回答に、`[]`があるのでTypeScriptでは？と言っている人がいますが、違います。

下記は、allowedMentionsに空白を入れることで、メンションをされないようになります。

```
message.reply({
  content: "hoge",
  allowedMentions: []
});
```